# Can't get Ubuntu Mate on NOOBS?

Tags: noobs, image, ubuntu, osmc

So Ubuntu mate is now an 'official' third party OS I guess:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/

I'd like to install it to try it out, I know how to install using a .img file, no problem.

The problem is that I would like to install it using NOOBS instead, but Ubuntu Mate isn't a downloadable option when using NOOBS, but all the other OS's are. I like to have 2 OS's; one media player, and one regular distro, otherwise I would just not use NOOBS.

I've looked at the README for NOOBS here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs#how-to-create-a-custom-os-version

but I can't quite figure out how to do it.
I figured out how to make the boot.tar.xz (from the ubuntu .img file) but I don't know how to make the root.tar.xz.

If someone could show me how to get NOOBS to install both Ubuntu Mate and OSMC on the same SD, that would be great.

Comment: Couldn't figure out a way to do it, gave up and just installed Ubuntu-MATE alone. Still it's a pretty great desktop, more feature rich than Raspbian, feels more like a real PC and less like a toy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently someone has uploaded a noobs image. It is recent and it works with the latest noobs version. Download it from here: [Ubuntu Mate](http://forum.xda-developers.com/devdb/project/dl/?id=15595). Unzip the archive and transfer the folder into the os folder of noobs and install noobs as usual.